# How can we check status document (synchronized or not ) in couchbase Lite

Tags: couchbase-lite

I'm new with couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway, When I add a new document in the off-line mode the document not synchronized , how can I check whether document synchronize to sever or not ?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the same question from the Couchbase Forum:

> The iOS/Mac [and Java] implementation has a method CBLReplication.isDocumentPending that does this (in versions 1.2+.) I don't think it's been ported to the other implementations yet.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-can-we-check-status-document-synchronized-or-not-in-couchbase-lite/8614

Comment: Thanks Chippiewill and Jens Alfke for support me this case :)